# How do I upgrade everything on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt

When I tried to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, this is the message logs shown after `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Notice the last line, how do I forcefully update those 961 items?

```
    ..........................................................................
    ..........................................................................   
          xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-vivid
          xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid
          xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-vivid
          xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-vivid
          xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-vivid
          xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-vivid
          xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-vivid
          xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-vivid
          xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-vivid
          xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-vivid
          xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-vivid
          xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-vivid yelp zeitgeist-core zenity zenity-common
        0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 961 not upgraded.
```

Comment: `apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: @jordanm : This worked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`apt-get upgrade` plays it safe: it upgrades all the packages that can be upgraded without breaking other packages. If upgrading package A requires uninstalling package B, `apt-get upgrade` won't do it, and A ends up in the “not upgraded” list.

Over time, packages get broken into pieces, joined together, renamed, etc. In addition to basic dependencies (A requires B), a package C can declare that it “replaces” a package B, indicating that when C is installed, it should be ok to uninstall B. Apt also has a concept of automatically-installed vs manually-installed package; it should be ok to remove an automatically-installed package even if it isn't explicitly getting replaced, whereas manually-installed packages are requested by the user and should stay. But `apt-get upgrade` doesn't take any risk.

There is another command **`apt-get dist-upgrade`** which is willing to remove packages if necessary. The idea is that `apt-get upgrade` only upgrades individual packages, whereas `apt-get dist-upgrade` upgrades the whole distribution. `apt-get upgrade` is low-risk and you can pretty much do it without paying attention, whereas `apt-get dist-upgrade` might occasionally remove a program that you rely on, especially if you haven't taken care to mark all the packages you absolutely need as manually installed. You're unlikely to end up with a broken system after `apt-get dist-upgrade`, but sometimes you might need to reinstall a package or two.

Aptitude has the same command duality, but has introduced prefered synonyms:
`safe-upgrade`=`upgrade`   vs.   `full-upgrade`=`dist-upgrade`.

In addition, Ubuntu provides a program called `do-release-upgrade` which is the [recommended way to upgrade from one Ubuntu release to the next](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html) (or from one Ubuntu LTS to the next). This program runs `apt-get dist-upgrade` under the hood, but makes some checks and preparations first and performs some cleanup afterwards.

In summary:

- If upgrading between Ubuntu releases, use `do-release-upgrade`.
- If you're just installing security updates and bug fixes, use `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get upgrade` (or `aptitude safe-upgrade`).
- Otherwise use `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get dist-upgrade` (or `aptitude full-upgrade`).

Answer (score 3):

You did not say how you got there.  But the first thing to do would be to check *how* to upgrade.  Advice is easy to find, e.g., [How To Upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-to-16-04/), which comes to the point by saying to run

```
sudo update-manager -d
```